# get next ID attribute from ul list

Tags: jquery, html, list

I have a list with values for test purpose its just 1-4..Now when I click on the button I'd like to get the next one in that list.  Now I assume I would have to store in a variable the current one I'm on?

```
var current = 1;
function getnext(){
alert($('#list li').next().attr('id'));
    //update current with next value from list
}

<input type="button" onclick="getnext();" value="next" />
<ul id="list">
<li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
    <li id="4"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('#list li')` gets _all_ matching elements, not just the first one. Where do you think you're storing the "current" one?

Comment: i though about having a var current = 1; and then updating it in the function with the next li's id?

Comment: Sure, that sounds fine. But that's nothing like your current code.

Comment: Ok updated the question with that variable.

Comment: I don't know what happend to one of the answers here worked and its what i'm using but it's deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var current = 1;
function getnext(){
   current++;
   if (current > MAX_COUNT_HERE) {
     current = 1;
   }
   var el = document.getElementById(current);
   alert(el.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var current = 0;
var listItems = $('#list li');
function getnext(){
    //check if you haven't reached the end of the list yet...
    if(current < listItems.length()) {
      alert(listItems[current]);
      current++;
    }
    //update current with next value from list
}
```